# Одна из точек входа не попадает в сборку

Tags: javascript, webpack

При сборке проекта содержимое последней точки входа не попадает в итоговую сборку:

```
entry: {
    settings: "./table/static/table/js/script1.js",
    detail: "./table/static/table/js/script2.js"
},
output: {
    path: __dirname + "/common/static/js",
    filename: "bundle.js"
},
```

в коде `bundle.js` отсутствует содержимое `script2.js`. Почему так?

Файл `script2.js` имеется в графе зависимостей, который можно построить на сервисе вебпака http://webpack.github.io/analyse/#modules

Я правильно понимаю принцип сборки бандла - содержимое всех точек входа объединяется в моем случае в один файл? Или мне надо в один файл импортировать все объекты со всех файлов, которые задействованы в проекте?

Comment: вроде бы количество точек входа должно совпадать с количеством выходных файлов. но не уверен

Comment: на сколько понимаю доки, нет. мы можем собрать все в один бандл, который встроим в базовый шаблон, а можем разбить по чанкам

Comment: Ага, значит перепутал все :)

Comment: @Grundy я сам еще плаваю в доках)

Comment: точки входа пробовали массивом задавать? `entry: ['pathToFile1', 'pathToFile2']`

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, разве должна быть разница?

Comment: @Grundy разница есть если её заложили разработчики) я раньше так собирал, а не через объект с ключами. Но сейчас уже не найду ту конфигурацию.

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев хм, заработало. но почему? в доках указан способ из моего вопроса http://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html#running-multiple-entry-points . оформите, пожалуйста, как ответ, я вам плюс поставлю

Comment: @while1pass, [документация](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#entry)

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев понял, кажется. способ с ключами подразумевает разбиение на куски, а для объединения - использование CommonChunksPlugin, а я его отключил

Comment: @while1pass https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html вот тут я тогда нашел информацию о подключении в блоке `entry` все хорошо описано, что и в каких случаях нужно подключать

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев спасибо, прочитал. только вопрос? как на практике использутся чанки? понимаю, чтобы не грузить целиком сборку, она может быть большой для проекта. что еще? правильно понимаю, что одна страница - один чанк?

Comment: для вас статьи https://habrahabr.ru/post/307694/ https://habrahabr.ru/post/308926/ Хорошего коддинга и с наступающим! :) Чанк это как отдельный модуль/зависимость, чтобы не грузить все в одну точку, часто разбивают на несколько. В постах хорошо описано поведение

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев спасибо за статьи, да, в наступающем будем кодить